# Bootstrap input text in center of column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap but with a non-collapse nav. I'm trying to have the search form placed in center of the col-md-6. I seem to have tried everything so far but nothing works but it still aligns left in the column. Anyone know how I can achieve that?

**Here's my code:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container" style="margin-top:14px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><%= image_tag ("logo.png") %></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="navbar-header search">
                        <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></input>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" style="margin-top:7px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with following set of CSS rules:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">&lt;%= image_tag ("logo.png") %&gt;</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" style="
    text-align: center;
">
                        <div class="text-center navbar-header search" style="
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
">
                        <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" style="margin-top:7px;text-decoration:none;font-weight:bold;">Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Make alignment within central column div `text-align: center;` and display the block with `float: none;`.

**Here is plunk with properties assigned CSS classes: http://plnkr.co/edit/Iu3rnVK5dLi7fiaSHBRj?p=preview**

Comment: Thanks alot shershen! Worked great!!

Answer (score 1):

make it's position absolute, check in firebug if it is inheriting float from any other class. In bootstrap you have to beware of these things as well.

after doing this go for auto margin or try with top left positions by giving values in percentage values

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace the `div` parent with a `form` element you could do it without additional styles:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <form class="form-inline text-center">
        <input id="search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/catalinmunteanu/3f75ty5p/)

[Bootstrap alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)

Comment: Hi Catalin Munteanu, I've tried it. Strangely it doesn't work. The search form is still aligned left in the column. I got almost no custom css added except the width of the container set at 970px.

Comment: did you try that yourself ? seems not to work - http://plnkr.co/edit/z1UBaV5tL6rwkE9VG51q?p=preview

Comment: I've  edited my answer. If you can remove that div inside the `col-md-6` and instead use a `form` you should be good without any additional styles